TRUNCATE TABLE PARTITION takes hours when deleting an empty partition on Sybase ASE 16
We are having a performance issue with our sybase ASE database version 16.0.03.11.
The TRUNCATE TABLE x PARTITION y runs for hours although the actual partition has 0 records.
How does the truncate work when there are 0 records in the partition ? and why would this take so long ? The DROP PARTITION on the other hand is very quick. The table has millions of records and many indexes though the particular partition that is being truncated is empty.
How should I debug such an issue ? what kind of traces can be recorded or checks performed to understand what the DB is doing during the truncate statement.
Appreciate any help as I am not a DB expert.
Thank you

I remember we have similar issues when we dropped multiple rows in Oracle database.
Can you try do stats gathering on tables and indexes once and then see to truncate the table.
